# Spring MVC: manage Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8

I have this controller

```
public class WelcomeController extends ViewController {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SessionHelper sessionHelper;

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        sessionHelper.invalidate(request, new String[] { SubmitController.CONFIRMATION_INFO,
                                                         SubmitController.CONFIRMATION_INFO2,
                                                         SubmitController.CONFIRMATION_INFO3,
                                                         "changePrdStatus"  });                 
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        DetailedUser ecasUser = (DetailedUser)request.getUserPrincipal();

        User usr = userService.getUserFromLDAP(ecasUser);


..
}
```

that throws this Exception

```
com.tdk.iop.domain.security.ApplicationException: more than 1 user with the same email
        at com.tdk.iop.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.findByEmail(UserDaoImpl.java:195)
        at com.tdk.iop.services.impl.ServiceSupport.getEcasUser(ServiceSupport.java:46)
        at com.tdk.iop.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUserFromEcas(UserServiceImpl.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy596.getUserFromEcas(Unknown Source)
        at com.tdk.iop.controller.welcome.WelcomeController.handleRequest(WelcomeController.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
```

this on the web.xml

```
<error-page>
                <exception-type>com.tdk.iop.domain.security.ApplicationException</exception-type>
                <location>/errors/error500.do</location>
        </error-page>
```

But the application does not reach the `Error500Controller`

Comment: I think your issue is connected to the method signature. You configure *spring-mvc* to handle *ApplicationException*, but your method it throwing a more generic *Exception*.  Maybe you have to refine the *spring-mvc* configuration.

Comment: You have to add SimpleMappingExceptionHandler bean in your spring configuration xml.   Check this link https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of exception can be handled with *@ExceptionHandler*. For *e.g.* suppose you can get the number of users with same email through *usr.getNumberOfUserWithSameEmail()*

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        sessionHelper.invalidate(request, new String[] { SubmitController.CONFIRMATION_INFO,
                                                         SubmitController.CONFIRMATION_INFO2,
                                                         SubmitController.CONFIRMATION_INFO3,
                                                         "changePrdStatus"  });                 
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        DetailedUser ecasUser = (DetailedUser)request.getUserPrincipal();

        User usr = userService.getUserFromLDAP(ecasUser);

        Integer numOfUser = usr.getNumberOfUserWithSameEmail();
      if(numOfUser>1){
          throw new SameEmailException("more than 1 user with the same email");
         }
..
}
```

Then right after the above method, created a method that will intercept this `SameEmailException`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(SameEmailException.class) // UserNotFoundException.java
    public ModelAndView handleException(SameEmailException e) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("errorView"); 
        modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Then create a view that will show the message (errorView.jsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error! </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${errorMessage}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create separate class for the *`SameEmailException`* :

```
public class SameEmailException extends Exception {

    public SameEmailException (String message) {
        super(message);

    }
}
```